# How to forbid select value to appear and only echo result to be seen

Tags: php

In my case I use select and php code, everything works perfectly when I call the function but when printing the results, I get the following value for the echo, please for your help and opinion.

```
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="without_car">Without a car</option>
  </select>
```

```
    if($cars == "without_car") {
       $cars .= "You dont have a car.";
    } else {
        $cars .=  "You have a car.";
      }
```

I get the answer by calling through html:

```
'.$cars.'
```

The result if you choose "**Without a car**":

```
without_carYou dont have a car.
```

or

The result if you choose "**Volvo**":

```
volvoYou have a car.
```

How to forbid value to appear and only echo result to be seen?

I need the result to be as follows:

```
You have a car.
or
You dont have a car.
```

Comment: Give your variable a different name: `$carsInfo .='...'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenation reassign value of the variable:

```php
if($cars == "without_car") {
   $cars = "You dont have a car.";
} else {
   $cars = "You have a car.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend :) work!